# iPhone 7 no longer recognizes audio devices via the Lightning port

Tags: iphone, audio, lightning

I have an iPhone 7 and regularly play Music, Podcasts etc. through wired audio devices that connect via the Lightning connector: for example, [Apple Earpods with a Lightning connector](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMTN2AM/A/earpods-with-lightning-connector) and a [Belkin Lightning audio adapter](https://www.belkin.com/lightning-audio-charge/F8J198btWHT.html?gclid=CjwKCAjw3dCnBhBCEiwAVvLcu2e8AnSTAgp0ENYWdJDJknUf42DEtUa5USeuRAr-j67lPayY7tWTjxoCzx4QAvD_BwE) for connecting to an AUX cable.  Two days ago, my phone suddenly stopped recognizing all of these devices; audio plays through the phone's built-in speaker whether something is plugged in to the Lightning port or not.  Turning the phone off and back on didn't help; neither did unplugging the peripherals and plugging them back in.

I've verified that the EarBuds and Lightning Adapter both still work with a different iPhone, so I know the problem must be with the phone itself.  But the phone is still able to charge and sync through the Lightning port, so it seems unlikely that the problem is with the port.  I am also able to play audio through Bluetooth devices.

What else could be wrong?  Is it possible that some kind of setting got turned off or on?  Any suggestions for how to fix this?